# Using IIS Url Rewrite from HTTPS to another HTTPS

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to redirect my site from `https://localhost` (but written with the ip, like `https://10.0.7.8`) to another https location like `https://mysite.com`

My current configuration is:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to mysite.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="https://10.0.7.8*" />
      </conditions>
     </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And when I am accessing `https://10.0.7.8` it does not go to `https://mysite.com`, it stays on `https://10.0.7.8`

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the `https` part from the ip in 2 conditions:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to mysite.com" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^10\.0\.7\.8$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
     </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Also, `10.0.7.8` needs to be written `10\.0\.7\.8` because the `.` needs to be escaped as it is a special character.